# Selecting the most recent version of a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL server table that contains 4 relevant columns, `user (varchar), time (datetime), datestamp (datetime), deleted (bool).`

This table has some rows where the user and time are duplicates of other rows, and I am trying to write a query that will find all of these duplicated, and where a duplicate is found set the deleted flag on all rows except that with the most recent datestamp.

So far I have got a list of all duplicate users + times in a temporary table using

```
SELECT user, time into temp_duplicates from table where deleted = 0
GROUP BY user, time
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

and am now looking for a way to separate the most recent version of each row from any other copies of the row.

Answer (score 2):

No need to create an temporary table.
It can be solved with an update query like this:

```
update table set deleted = 1 where 
  deleted = 0 and
  exists (select * from table t2 where t2.user = table.user 
  and t2.time = table.time and t2.datestamp > table.datestamp)
```

It sets the deleted flag on all rows with a newer user/time row.